# Multiple occurrences in sed substitution

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to retrieve some data within a specific div tag in my html file.

My current html code is in the following format.

```
<div class = "class0">
    <div class = "class1">
         <div class = "class2">
             some text some text
         </div>
         Some more text
    </div>
    Too much text
</div>
```

When I try to extract tag in just the div with class2, using the bash code

```
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba
        s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g
        s/.*<div class\="class2">\(.*\).*/\1/g' test.html > out.html
```

I get the output html file with the code as

```
some text some text </div> Some more text </div> Too much text
```

I want all the data after the first `</div>` to be removed but instead the final one is being replaced.
Can someone please elaborate my mistake.

Comment: Consider a script instead of sed: while IFS='' read line ; do <<process line in finite state machine>> ; done > out.html --- I think you'll find it much easier.

Comment: @BruceK Or perhaps something similar in awk?

Comment: m fairly new to sed and no idea about awk. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: awk "scripts" are more script-like than sed scripts.  Once you're beyond the level of "trivial" in sed, it (to me) becomes a write-only language. :)  Anyway, "man awk" and there's an answer below.

Comment: You would probably do better to use an HTML parser to parse HTML. HTML is not a regular language, so attempting to use regular expressions to parse it will often lead to frustration and over-complication.

Comment: Have you tried either of the two answers? Are you still having any problems?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in awk:

```
awk '/class2/,/<\/div>/ {a[++i]=$0}END{for (j=2;j<i;++j) print a[j]}' file
```

Between the lines that match `/class2/` and `/<\/div>/`, write the contents to an array. At the end of the file loop through the array, skipping the first and last lines.

Instead of making an array, you could check for the first and last lines using a regular expression:

```
awk '/class2/,/<\/div>/ {if (!/class2|<\/div>/) print}' file
```

Comment: /class="classe/,/<\/div>/{print $0}

Answer (score 0):

This works for retrieving text inside the div class = "class2" tags

```
#!/bin/bash

htmlcode='
<div class = "class0">
    <div class = "class1">
        <div class = "class2">
            some text some text
        </div>
        Some more text
    </div>
   Too much text
</div>
'

echo $htmlcode |
sed -e's,<,\
<,g' |
grep 'div class = "class2"' |
sed -e's,>,>\
,g'|
grep -v 'div class = "class2"'
```

Comment: Sed commands with the escape \ character are escaping the new line so that sed will add a new line character where the pattern matches,  and grep can then filter the results.